# HTML Fluid Multi Column Layout (newspaper) for text

Tags: css

Is there any CSS technique or a good js technique for laying out content so that you have a "newspaper" like page. Given a div (or whatever) containing a bunch of content to split that content into N columns which total some pre-defined width.

Lets say with an N = 3, assuming my content is sorted A -> Q will render data in the following way:

```
 A  G  M
 B  H  N
 C  I  O
 D  J  P
 E  K  Q
 F  L
```

Any ideas? I'd like to not split the data on the server before rendering 3 divs so that I don't need to really calculate how the data will be rendered. However that is a last resort that can happen.

Comment: what would you like your layout to do if content overflows past the last column?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is bit late to really answer the Dmitriy, but for anyone passing by this question, here is a github project,from the Financial Times, that will do this for you:
FTColumnflow:
https://github.com/ftlabs/ftcolumnflow
Here is the list of features of the project:

- Configurable column widths, gutters and margins
- Fixed-position elements
- Elements spanning columns
- Keep-with-next to avoid headings at the bottom of a column
- No-wrap class to avoid splitting elements across columns
- Grouping of columns into pages
- Horizontal or vertical alignment of pages
- Standardised line height to align text baseline to a grid
- Rapid reflow as required by events such as device orientation or font-size change

Comment: Yes that works fine in al browsers except IE ... Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Sat, 31 Aug 2013 09:32:45 UTC


Message: Expected ':'
Line: 1320
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/blog/src/FTColumnflow.js