# CSS inline-block uneven spacing

Tags: html, css, layout

So I have two columns of cards and each card has the `inline-block` property. Each is of variable height so there is uneven white space in between each card like so:

[image: inline-block]

Short of having two separate columns, how can I get spacing between each card even?

I'm aiming for this layout:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some html/css or a jsfiddle? It would help those of us trying to help you

Comment: Also some idea of how this is **supposed** to look....it's not clear at present.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry about that. I'll update it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Fluid Multi Column Layout (newspaper) for text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798457/html-fluid-multi-column-layout-newspaper-for-text)

Answer (score 2):

Either use `column` layout, like so:

```
.cards {
  columns: 300px 2;
}

.cards div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or use a flex layout:

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* or column if you want them displayed vertically */
}
.cards div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Or if you just want them displayed at the top always:

```
.cards div {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```